# Круговая диаграмма на чистом css

Tags: html, css3

Можно ли сделать подобную круговую диаграмму, только средствами css?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Comment: @alexanderbarakin для начала думаю надо автора предупредить чтобы переформулировал вопрос, впервые же пишет здесь)

Comment: А зачем это делать на css, если можно взять к примеру svg?

Comment: @HamSter какой код вы ожидаете, если автор даже примерно не знает, как это делается? Белый div с border-radius: 50%?

Comment: @HamSter не нужно доводить до абсурда

Answer (score 9):

Вариант с css:

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #2b2b2b;
}

.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: #fff;
}

.box-inner {
  position: absolute;
  top: 5px;
  left: 5px;
  right: 5px;
  bottom: 5px;
  z-index: 5;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background:#2b2b2b;
}

.box span {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  top:50%;
  transform:translateY(-50%);
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  color:#fff;
  z-index: 10;
}

.box:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  
  clip: rect(0 200px 100px 0);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  background: #50c690;
}

.box:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  
  clip: rect(0 100px 200px 0);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(150deg);
  transform: rotate(150deg);
  background: #50c690;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-inner">
    <span>68%</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Источник codepen](https://codepen.io/seanstopnik/pen/Abyhj?editors=1000)

---

Вариант с `svg`:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #2b2b2b;
}

.circular-chart {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto;
  max-width: 200px;
  max-height: 200px;
}

.circle-bg {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 2;
}

.percentage {
  fill: #fff;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 10px;
  text-anchor: middle;
}

.circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke-width: 2;
  /* stroke-linecap: round; */
  stroke: #50c690;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="single-chart">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 36 36" class="circular-chart">
      <path class="circle-bg"
            d="M18 2.0845
               a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
               a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
            />
      <path class="circle"
            stroke-dasharray="68, 100"
            d="M18 2.0845
               a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 31.831
               a 15.9155 15.9155 0 0 1 0 -31.831"
            />
      <text x="18" y="20.35" class="percentage">68%</text>
    </svg>
</div>
```

[Источник medium.com с подробным описанием](https://medium.com/@pppped/how-to-code-a-responsive-circular-percentage-chart-with-svg-and-css-3632f8cd7705)

**P.S:** задайте в поиске *"css circle chart"*  и найдете еще больше примеров.

Comment: @Arthur, тем что вандалить не нужно! Вы влезли в мой код!!! Не оцениваю! А по другим правкам - убирать пробелы - это не необходимые правки!

Comment: @Arthur, и без обид!!! ;))))

Answer (score -1):

На чистом css нет скорее всего, всё-таки нужен будет JS. На чистом css можно максимум крутилку без всего написать.

Comment: если вы не знаете ответа можете добавить комментарий к вопросу, его тоже увидят. воздержитесь от ответов не решающих вопрос. нахватаете минусов только

Comment: @Arendach не может, рейтинга не хватает

Comment: Это неправильный ответ.